# Replacing entries in a Pandas column of lists and summing these new lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe column like this:

```
Name
[A,B,C]
[B,B,B]
[A,B,B]
```

And reference dataframe with "values" representing each item in array:

```
Key Value
A   1
B   2
C   3
```

I want to multiply each value in array by his score and sum it. So it would look like this:

```
Name      Value
[A,B,C]   6
[B,B,B]   6
[A,B,B]   5
```

I know i can use two loops and compare each others, but is there any more efficient way to avoid using loops?

Comment: By multiply, you mean replace, yes?

Comment: Yes, replace them and sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

If you have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Name':[['A','B','C'],['B','B','B'],['A','B','B']]})
ref= pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Key':['A','B','C'], 'Value': [1,2,3]})
```

Then, you can do:

```
df2=df.explode('Name').replace(dict(zip(ref['Key'],ref['Value'])))
df['Value']=df2.groupby(df2.index).sum()
```

`df` will be:

```
        Name  Value
0  [A, B, C]      6
1  [B, B, B]      6
2  [A, B, B]      5
```